# Convert F to FF using left shift operator

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I have UINT64 variable. In start it is initialized to 0xF. Now I want this to change on runtime depending on some input. Its value will increase on runtime. But what I want is that it should change from F to FF, from FF to FFF, one F should be appended to it.

Now here is my code.

```
UINT64 mapFileSize = 0xF;
while (mapFileSize < someUserInput)
    // add one F to mapFileSize;
```

What should I write there. I am trying left shift operator but it is not working fine.

```
mapFileSize <<= 1;
```

I am doing this but this does not give me desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more succinct way of doing it:

```
mapFileSize |= (mapFileSize << 4);
```

Or if you can't guarantee that the original value always ends in 0xf:

```
mapFileSize = (mapFileSize << 4) | 0x0f;
```

Answer (score 5):

leftshift mapFileSize 4 bit

and then or the mapFileSize with 0xF

```
 mapFileSize = mapFileSize  <<4;
 mapFileSize = mapFileSize  | 0xF;
```

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is not the result of a single shift. A `<<` just shifts the bits, shifting in zeros as needed, but you would need to shift in ones which is something C's left-shift operator just doesn't do.

You need to first shift, and then set the lowest four bits to all ones:

```
mapFileSize <<= 4;  /* Shift to the left one hexadecimal digit. */
mapFileSize |= 0xf; /* Make sure rightmost digit is f. */
```

Answer (score 1):

$F$ shifted left by four is $0F0$, not $FF$. So you need:

```
mapFileSize <<= 4 ;
mapFileSize += 0x0F ;
```